# messaging between native web components v1

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have two native web components in a nested setup like below

```
<top-nav theme="aqua">
  <nav-link selected>Dashboard</nav-link>
  <nav-link>Settings</nav-link>
  <nav-link>Profile</nav-link>
  <nav-link>Logout</nav-link>
</fancy-tabs>
```

The rendering works fine for each component individually but now I need to add communication between them.

Simplest use-case is to set a link to be selected.

By default dashboard is selected link.

Now when I click settings link, settings link becomes selected, but how do I tell the dashboard component to remove the selected attribute because only one link can be active at any moment.

I am thinking to fire an event from clicked element, catch the event in top-nav element, then loop through all children and remove selected attrib if the element is not the origin of the event.

But this looks very Jquery era approach and something is not right about that.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is :

- save a reference to the currently selected element
- to listen to click events at the `<top-nav>` container level,
- when you catch an event `event`, inspect its `target` to get the clicked `<nav-link>` child,
- refresh the old and new `<nav-link>` elements.

```js
selected = tn.querySelector('nav-link[selected]')
tn.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  if (selected != ev.target) {
    selected.removeAttribute('selected')
    selected = ev.target
    selected.setAttribute('selected', '')
  }
})
```

```css
nav-link { cursor: pointer }
nav-link[selected] { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<top-nav id="tn" theme="aqua">
  <nav-link selected>Dashboard</nav-link>
  <nav-link>Settings</nav-link>
  <nav-link>Profile</nav-link>
  <nav-link>Logout</nav-link>
</top-nav>
```